# How can I combine each value of different keys of a dictionary to outcome a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, grid-search

I want to create a grid of params from a dictionary, each key is a param name, and they contain a list of values. I want to combine all values between them.

```
params = {'k1': [1, 2, 3], 'k2': [10, 20, 30]}
```

In R, I can create it expanding a list using `expand.grid`. And it creates a data.frame:

```
> params <- list("k1" = c(1, 2, 3), "k2" = c(10, 20, 30))
> params
# $k1
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $k2
# [1] 10 20 30

> expand.grid(params)
#   k1 k2
# 1  1 10
# 2  2 10
# 3  3 10
# 4  1 20
# 5  2 20
# 6  3 20
# 7  1 30
# 8  2 30
# 9  3 30
```

Is there a way to do it in a straight-forward manner in Python ?

Obs. I need to outcome this `data.frame`. I will not use `GridSearchCV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order will be a little different, but this is a job for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(product(*params.values()), columns=params.keys())

   k1  k2
0   1  10
1   1  20
2   1  30
3   2  10
4   2  20
5   2  30
6   3  10
7   3  20
8   3  30
```

On older versions of pandas, you may need to listify the product first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(*params.values())), columns=params.keys())
```